# How do I make a Bootstrap Navigation and a Carousel fit together at 100vh?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to fit the bootstrap navigation and the carousel together on the screen without any overflow. In other words, I want the navigation and the carousel to fit together in 100vh without any overflow.

I tried to add `img-fluid: 100vh;` but that makes the carousel overflow when I scroll all the way to the top.

I also tried to add a div around the Navigation, and the Carousel, and tried adding a `100vh` to that but that didn't work.

Here is the code in codepen as well. Thank you for your help.
https://codepen.io/christiangutierrezreyez/pen/vwpQdN

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!--BOOTSTRAP CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- FONTAWESOME CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--TITLE-->
  <title>Document</title>

<!-- CUSTOM CSS -->
<style>
.img-fluid {
  height: 100vh;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- BODY -->
  <div id="navslider-vh"></div>
  <!-- NAVIGATION -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light mb-3">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- BRAND -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <!-- LINK 1 -->
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <!-- LINK 2 -->
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <!-- LINK 3 -->
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <!-- LINK 4 -->
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- END NAVIGATION -->


  <!-- CAROUSEL -->
  <div id="MagicCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- CAROUSEL INDICATORS-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#MagicCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#MagicCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#MagicCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#MagicCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#MagicCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol> <!-- END CAROUSEL INDICATORS-->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <!-- SLIDE 1 -->
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080" alt="First Slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Cinderalla</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- SLIDE 2 -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080" alt="Second Slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Cinderalla</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- SLIDE 3 -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080" alt="Third Slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Snow White</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- SLIDE 4 -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080" alt="Fourth Slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Snow White</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- SLIDE 5 -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080" alt="Fifth Slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Beauty and the Beast</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- SLIDE 6 -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080" alt="Sixth Slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Pokahauntes</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- CONTROLS -->
      <a href="#MagicCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" class="carousel-control-prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#MagicCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next" class="carousel-control-next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>


    </div><!-- END CAROUSEL INNER -->
  </div><!-- END CAROUSEL -->
  </div> <!-- END NAVSLIDER-VH -->>

</body> <!-- END OF BODY -->
<!-- JQUERY JS-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- POPPER JS-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- BOOTSTRAP JS -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>


  [1]: https://codepen.io/christiangutierrezreyez/pen/vwpQdN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `mb-3` class from `nav` then this css would work:

```css
#MagicCarousel,
#MagicCarousel > div,
#MagicCarousel > div > div > img{
    height: calc(100vh - 56px);
}
```

...where "56px" is the height of the `nav`

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could do calculations like that in CSS. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#MagicCarousel{
  height:90vh;
}
.navbar{
  height:10vh
}
.carousel-inner , .carousel-item{
height:100%;

}
.carousel-item{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!--BOOTSTRAP CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- FONTAWESOME CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--TITLE-->
  <title>Document</title>

<!-- CUSTOM CSS -->
</head>

<body>
  <!-- BODY -->
  <div id="navslider-vh"></div>
  <!-- NAVIGATION -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- BRAND -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <!-- LINK 1 -->
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <!-- LINK 2 -->
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <!-- LINK 3 -->
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <!-- LINK 4 -->
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- END NAVIGATION -->


  <!-- CAROUSEL -->
  <div id="MagicCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- CAROUSEL INDICATORS-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#MagicCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#MagicCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#MagicCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#MagicCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#MagicCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol> <!-- END CAROUSEL INDICATORS-->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <!-- SLIDE 1 -->
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080" alt="First Slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Cinderalla</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- SLIDE 2 -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100 " src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080" alt="Second Slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Cinderalla</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- SLIDE 3 -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080" alt="Third Slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Snow White</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- SLIDE 4 -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100 " src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080" alt="Fourth Slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Snow White</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- SLIDE 5 -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100 " src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080" alt="Fifth Slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Beauty and the Beast</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- SLIDE 6 -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080" alt="Sixth Slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Pokahauntes</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- CONTROLS -->
      <a href="#MagicCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" class="carousel-control-prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#MagicCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next" class="carousel-control-next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>


    </div><!-- END CAROUSEL INNER -->
  </div><!-- END CAROUSEL -->
  </div> <!-- END NAVSLIDER-VH -->

</body> <!-- END OF BODY -->
<!-- JQUERY JS-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- POPPER JS-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- BOOTSTRAP JS -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

this is it! hope this help!